# Adding chamfer to box using CSS3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm building a project website for our compound, and right now I'm building a news-feed for the landingpage.

Earlier, the news-feed boxes (its divided into three boxes/row) was just genuine text; now it involves both text and images. Earlier, I could simply use CSS gradients to create the requested effect. The problem lies in that I can't seem to get it to work properly with image-backgrounds.

I have tried to solve the problem using image-borders, but it didn't work due to the fact that it needs to be transparent so it matches the body-background but still covering the image-background.

My question is as it follows:
Can I create the requested chamfer effect on the news-feed boxes that would work never-regarding what's the background of the body or if it's a image/genuine text?

Please take a look at the jsfiddle to understand what effect the first text-only box has and what I want to do with the second image/text-box; http://jsfiddle.net/pm6hqtxq/1/

Code for chamfer:

```
background:linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 20px, #333333 0) top left, linear-gradient(0deg, transparent 0px, #333333 0) top right, linear-gradient(0deg, transparent 0px, #333333 0) bottom right, linear-gradient(0deg, transparent 0px, #333333 0) bottom left;
```

Thanks,
Tommie

Comment: This would be pretty easy if you use SVG for this.

Comment: @GaryHayes Any suggestions how? In which way should I use an SVG?

Comment: The proper term you want to use is "chamfer", not triangle border box.

Comment: @GaryHayes I'm sorry for my bad English grammar :)

Comment: http://www.svgbasics.com/paths.html

Comment: @GaryHayes Still can't figure out how you think this would work out. How should the code look? How would the SVG be able to be placed above the image in the z-axis but still be transparent?

Comment: Give the SVG an id and treat it like a div. Manipulate the z-index with css.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the css way to do it.

[Fiddle HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/S2nqK/209/)

```
    background: #c00; /* fallback */
    background:
        -moz-linear-gradient(45deg,  transparent 15px, #c00 10px),
        -moz-linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 15px, #c00 10px),
        -moz-linear-gradient(225deg, transparent 15px, #c00 10px),
        -moz-linear-gradient(315deg, transparent 15px, #c00 10px);
    background:
        -o-linear-gradient(45deg,  transparent 15px, #c00 10px),
        -o-linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 15px, #c00 10px),
        -o-linear-gradient(225deg, transparent 15px, #c00 10px),
        -o-linear-gradient(315deg, transparent 15px, #c00 10px);
    background:
        -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg,  transparent 15px, #c00 10px),
        -webkit-linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 15px, #c00 10px),
        -webkit-linear-gradient(225deg, transparent 15px, #c00 10px),
        -webkit-linear-gradient(315deg, transparent 15px, #c00 10px);
}
```