# Chamfer / Fillet Image HTML

Tags: html, css, image

I have an image and I'm looking at basic customisation for a small website I'm creating in HTML.

I understand you can chamfer an image, as seen on [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26597769/adding-chamfer-to-box-using-css3WQAiBP8sDaKN-bWGwneNet_EA&ust=1480249125836885), that gives a 45Degree cut.

I'm hoping for a more rounded Chamfer on each corner? (I believe it's called a Fillet but I'm not 100% sure of the correct terminology.

As seen in the second picture:

[image]

Using `border-radius: 16px 16px 16px 16px;` works by putting it in the `img` class, but I don't want all images affected.

What do I need to do to allow only select images to be chamfered?

I tried this, but it didn't work:

```
.img-chamfer {
    border-radius: 16px 16px 16px 16px;
}

<div class="img-chamfer"> 
    <img src="Test.png" >
</div>
```

My exact code can be found here: https://jsfiddle.net/netazv40/

```css
.main {
  color:#29abe2;
  text-align: center
}
  
.img-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
}

.img-wrapperPadding {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto 32px;
}
  
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  width: auto\9; /* ie8 */
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
    <div class="img-wrapper">
        <div class="img-wrapperPadding">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/350x208" width="350" height="208"><br/>
            <img src="http://placehold.it/100x50" width="100" height="50">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="img-wrapper">
        <div class="img-wrapperPadding">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/350x208" width="350" height="208"><br/>
            <img src="http://placehold.it/100x50" width="100" height="50">
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

I only need the larger image to be affected/chamfered.

Comment: Search about border-radius in css.

Comment: `<div><img src="Test.png" class="img-chamfer" /></div>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**solution after providing your fiddle**

You can use the following CSS rule:

```
.img-wrapperPadding img[width="350"] {
    border-radius:16px;
}
```

> **Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/netazv40/3/

... or add a class to your image and solve it like the following:

```css
.rborder {
  border-radius:16px;
}
```

```html
<img class="rborder" src="http://placehold.it/100x100"/>
```

> **Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/netazv40/1/

**solution #1 (using `flexbox`):**

```css
.img-chamfer {
  border-radius:16px;
  display:inline-flex;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-chamfer">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
</div>
```

**solution #2 (using `inline-block`):**

```css
.img-chamfer {
  border-radius:16px;
  display :inline-block;
  overflow:hidden;
  font-size:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-chamfer">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
</div>
```

Comment: I actually have my image in a wrapper, that links a second image using `display: inline-block;`, then a vertical wrapper using `display: block;` and this method breaks my wrapper :(

Comment: show full code and provide a fiddle. I can't see your wrappers!

Comment: Sorry. I always forget about Fiddle, and was trying to make the question simpler to read. I have updated my question and included a fiddle which is my exact code :) Thanks again.

Comment: Thank you so much. Perfect. Works great. I went with the `.rborder` solution as I have a varied size of images that will need chamfering. Thanks again for posting.

Answer (score 0):

You can use border-radius like,

```
div {
    border: 3px solid;
    border-radius: 30px;
}
```